# Can I deploy a farm solution to my site collection only

Tags: 2013, deployment, visual-web-part, solution-package, farm-solution

I have created a visual web part using visual studio of type "Farm solution", then I add the wsp file using the following command:-

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Add-SPSolution c:\RedirectManagedMetaData.wsp
```

after that this solution appeared under the "CA>>System Setting>>Manage Farm Solutions", as follow:-

[image]

now from the central administration I only have the option to deploy it to web application/s level, while in my case I only need this wsp solution to be inside single site collection and not to all site collections within my web application. So is there a way to deploy a farm solution to specific site collection/s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to deploy a solution to a particular site collection. A solution is deployed either Globally to all web applications or a single web application. It is the feature inside the solution which can be deployed to a farm/webapplication/site collection/web.

Comment: but if i chose to deploy to web application , then then this feature will be activated automatically to all site collections.. atleast is there a way to not forcing the feature to get activated insdie the CS features ?

Comment: Change the Scope of the feature to `Site`. That way it won't be automatically activated.

Comment: Features are not activated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you deploy your farm solution to web application, but you activate solution's feature(s) only on desired site collection.

Answer (score -1):

Set Your Feature Scope to "Site" instead of "Farm".